# tsql 'in' statement to table valued function

Tags: t-sql

I have simple table valued function returning one column table

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetProducersByWheelType] 
(       
    @wheeltype int  
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(   
    SELECT ProducerId 
    FROM ProducersByWheelTypes 
    WHERE WheelType=@wheeltype  
)
```

and what i need is to know if i can call the way like :

```
select * 
from producers 
where producerid in ( fnGetProducersByWheelType(2))
```

not

```
select * 
from producers 
where producerid in (
    select productId 
    from fnGetProducersByWheelType(2)
)
```

i.e. not mention single column productId 'select productId from'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. As the documentation for [`in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) shows you may have either a subquery or list of expressions. A TVF is not an [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 3):

You can do `INNER JOIN` instead:

```
select p.* 
from producers p
join fnGetProducersByWheelType(2) f 
    on p.producerid = f.producerid
```

Comment: thanks, i meant no mention this single column to reduce code

Comment: @LapenkovVladimir, no shortcuts here, unfortunately :-)